# output filenames when using mv command linux

Tags: linux, exec, mv

I was wondering if there is a way to output the list of files moved when using the mv command in a shell script?

I am moving files from one directory to another on the same server
I'm using a shell script with the following:
find path/to/source/ -type -f -name "CC*.txt -mmin+1 -exec mv {} /path/to/destination \;

This is also called via a crontab

Comment: Did you try `mv -v ....`

Comment: I did but nothing happened - and no files were moved

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

`mv source/* destination/ | ll destination/ > /tmp/list.txt`

You can use `ll` OR `ls` according to your need.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried: find path/to/source/ -type -f -name "CC*.txt -mmin+1 -exec mv {} /path/to/destination | ll /path/to/destination > /tmp/list.txt \; but I got a missing exec error